# Serilalization of subclasses

Tags: java, serialization

I just read the [Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) documentation and was kind of surprised by this (emphasized mine):

> The `writeObject` method is responsible for writing the state of the
>   object for its particular class so that the corresponding readObject
>   method can restore it. The default mechanism for saving the Object's
>   fields can be invoked by calling `out.defaultWriteObject`. **The method**
>   ***does not need* to concern itself with the state belonging to its**
>   **superclasses or subclasses**. State is saved by writing the individual
>   fields to the `ObjectOutputStream` using the `writeObject` method or by
>   using the methods for primitive data types supported by DataOutput.

So, it's not guaranteed that `superclass`'s will be serialized in the following case:

```
public class MySuperClass implements Serializable{
    public int a;
}

public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass{
    public int b;
}

MySubClass msc = new MySubClass();
msc.a = 10
msc.b = 20

//serialize msc
```

So, it's implementation specific if the value of deserialized `msc.a` will be `10` or `0`?

Comment: How did you translate "does not need to concern" into "is not guaranteed"?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, my misunderstanding of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `writeObject` and `readObject` does not refer to the methods of `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream`, but to methods you may optionally implement in your own class, if you require a different serialization behavior than the default. This part of the documentation says what you need concern yourself with or not, when implementing these methods. But since you are not using this feature in your example, this part of the documentation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation just above the paragraph you've excerpted it says that the *classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods*. These methods are writeObject and readObject methods as @Beethoven mentioned.

As for the question you asked about the value of msc.a it definetely will be 10. It would be 0 if your superclass does not implement *Serializable* but subclass does. Even your superclass does not implement *Serializable* you could give a default value to msc.a in a noarg constructor.